# Safari can't connect to secure laravel websocket

Tags: websocket, safari, laravel-websockets

I'm running an app, where I use laravel-websockets, with the pusher replacement and a self created websocket instance. For SSL I used a letsencrypt certificate and the nginx reverse proxy "[Same location for websockets and web contents](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#same-location-for-websockets-and-web-contents)" approach. On my nginx TLS 1.2 and 1.3 is enabled. Now on Firefox and Chrome all is working fine, but on Safari (version 14.1.2, tested on a macOS Mojave 10.14.6) I get the following error in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/app/asdfasdf?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false' failed: Unexpected response code: 401
```

These are my echo options:

```
const echoOptions = {
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  wsHost: window.location.hostname,
  wsPort: 80,
  wssPort: 443,
  forceTLS: true,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], // <-- disable pusher api fallback
  disableStats: true,
};

window.Echo = new Echo(echoOptions);
```

I searched a lot for any kind of similar issues, but I can't find an answer.

Any ideas or help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figgered it out:

In the "getting started" installation section mentioned here:
https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation

They say install the latest stable version with:

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
```

This installs version [**1.12.0**](https://packagist.org/packages/beyondcode/laravel-websockets#1.12.0)

To fix this issue I just removed the stable version and installed the latest beta:

```
composer remove beyondcode/laravel-websockets
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets "2.0.0-beta.36"
```

I had some dependencies that can't be resolved, so I needed to downgrade doctrine/dbal from version 3.1 to 2.9.

Then I backed up my old config/websocket.php and published the new one of the new package with:

```
cp config/websocket.php config/websocket.old.php
rm config/websocket.php
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

There I adjusted some values, e.g. allowed_origin and enable_client_messages.

Finally don't forget to kill to old websockets:serve process (if its running) by searching the process id with **ps aux | grep websocket** and restart the websocket with:

```
kill <process id>
php artisan websockets:serve
```

PS:
I also updated **pusher/pusher-php-server** to version **5.0** not 3.0 as they mentioned [here](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher#requirements) and used the lates npm [pusher-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pusher-js) package 7.0.3